# Use PDO to extract value from database

Tags: php, mysql, api, pdo

I have a question: how do you I extract a value from database using pdo?
Current code:

```
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("pdocon.php");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmtt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
$code = $stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I am trying to get $code as a result of the mysql query "SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1" from the database. I don't know why but it's not working.

UPDATE:
Ok so this is the whole code of the php file that extracts $code and puts it in a URL link which is an API call. After running this php, I keep getting 0 values.

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("pdocon.php");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmtt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
$stmtt->execute(); 
$code = $stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($rs)) {
        if(time()-$rs["lastupdate"] < 604800) die($rs["cost"]);
}
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=(MYKEYHERE)&code=".$code."&names=".$item."&delimiter=!END!";
$string = file_get_contents($link);
$json = $string;

$obj = json_decode($json);
if($obj->{'status'} == "fail") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->{'price'};
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET `cost` = ?,`lastupdate` = ? WHERE `name` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($lowest_price, time(), $item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($item, $lowest_price, time()));
echo $lowest_price;
print_r($lowest_price);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't executed $stmtt, so there's no result set to fetch.

```
$stmtt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
$stmtt->execute();
$code = $stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `$stmtt->execute();
$code = $stmtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
Because you have no bind variables in `$stmtt`'s query, there are no arguments to `execute()`. Other than that, you handle it the same as the other prepared statement.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: If you want I can share screen on skype if you have time: bagdasar.bogdan

Comment: And explain what I'm trying to do

Comment: I don't skype, but we could [ use chat][http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94878/use-pdo-to-extract-value-from-database] (I hope I did that right.)

Comment: second I'll join now on my 2nd acc

Comment: In any case, do you see anything in the server error log?

Comment: Failed to load response data

Comment: Where'd you see the "Failed to load..." message? Also, can you add `print_r($code);` after the fetch() and tell me what you get?

Comment: I get  Array ( [auth] => 752172 ) 0 for the php file code I just copy paste as an edit above

Comment: Looks like it's working then; your query is running and returning a resultset. Any current problem is the result of something else. (I think.) The result in `$code` is an associative array with `key 'auth' -> value '752172'`.

Comment: Oh okay so that is working. But do you know why I get 0 for the cost?

Comment: For example: https://gyazo.com/88faf9d8dd1dc063b97d3244ecef7450 the price should be 1300 but it's displayed as 0

Comment: I think we should call this one answered and open a new question for this next problem, which at first glance looks to have something to do with JSON handling. (If you do open a new question, come back here and post a link just for interest's sake.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663589/api-call-extracted-string-with-json-decode-is-not-showing-up?noredirect=1#comment55100879_33663589  reference to new question